# Exploitation differences between Docker and VirtualBox for CVE-2010-4221

Tags: vulnerability, metasploit, cve, ftp, docker

I am currently working on a research project where I analyze exploits in different virtualized environments. As an example I picked [ProFTPd v1.3.3c](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/15662) which has a remote code execution vulnerability.

I did setup two environments:

1. A VirtualBox machine with Ubuntu which has the vulnerable ProFTPd version installed
2. A docker image via Ansible with the same exact vulnerable ProFTPd installation.

Now, to test if both can be exploited successfully I ran the metasploit module `exploit/unix/ftp/proftpd_133c_backdoor` and also the nmap script `--script ftp-proftpd-backdoor` against both environments. I noticed something interesting.

Against the VirtualBox Environment, both exploits ran successfully (giving code execution).
On the Docker environment the nmap script worked fine but the metasploit module didn't:

```
msf5 exploit(unix/ftp/proftpd_133c_backdoor) > run

[*] Started reverse TCP double handler on 172.17.0.1:4444 
[*] 172.17.0.2:21 - Connecting to FTP server 172.17.0.2:21...
[*] 172.17.0.2:21 - Connected to target FTP server.
[*] 172.17.0.2:21 - Sending Backdoor Command
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

I don't understand why. I first thought maybe there are differences in the network settings of Docker - but then the nmap script should not have worked either. While both exploit the same vulnerability, the metasploit module execute code via a buffer overflow it seems whereas the nmap script seem to inject a command?

It does not seem logical to me - because both environments have the exact same version installed, whereas one works and the other one does not. 
Is there anything I need to change so that the backdoor can connect back from the docker container? I already exposed port 21.

Comment: Might be helpful to compare a network capture for both attempts.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Thats a bit problematic cause there are no such utilities installed on either one of the machines. I could install wireshark or something similar I am not sure if that would get me anywhere tho.

Comment: the question needs more info, logs & captures etc. Otherwise, we can really only guess.